# Receiving SIGKILL when children terminate

Tags: signals, fork, wait

I want to receive SIGKILL instead of SIGCHLD when any of my forked children terminate. On Linux this is possible by passing a different child termination signal to `clone()`<sup>1</sup>.

Is this possible on any other Unix platforms, particularly macOS? I'm aware of the closing pipe trick and likely will implement that but just checking there isn't a better way.

1. See "The child termination signal" in the [`clone(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) docs.

Comment: This seems more like a programming question, and perhaps would do better on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).  It also seems like almost a perfect [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You have a problem that you've decided can be solved by replacing `SIGCHLD` with `SIGKILL`.  You're asking about making your already-selected solution work instead of asking how to solve the underlying problem. You're almost certainly not the first to have that underlying problem.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The underlying problem (killing all descendent processes robustly) has been asked many times and the answer is "on Linux it's possible but requires `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`; on FreeBSD it's easy; everywhere else it's impossible". I'm asking a specific question about Unix APIs that would make my ingenious attempt to solve "killing all descendent processes robustly" very slightly more robust.

Comment: Using `SIGKILL` to terminate a process is the antithesis of "robust" as any process killed in that manner has no opportunity to do anything.  In this case, if the parent process receives a `SIGKILL` upon any child terminating, the parent process will be killed immediately and orphan all other child processes.

Comment: No you can't say that you don't know the context. I am well aware that `SIGKILL` terminates processes and orphans its children.

Comment: Then you're also well aware that robust software has no need to be terminated via `SIGKILL`.

Comment: That's a very sweeping and totally unsupported statement.

Comment: [Hardly unsupported](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+is+sigkill+bad).  Or maybe you like your processes getting whacked in the middle of an IO operation and leaving buffers unflushed.  I'll be blunt:  if you really think going right to `SIGKILL` is a good idea, you have no idea what `SIGKILL` really means and why truly robust software doesn't need to be shutdown with `SIGKILL`.

Comment: A scenario where you're wrong: I need to capture the exit code of a child process, so I `wait(2)` on it. I also need to kill it if requested by the user, so I potentially `kill(2)` it. It's seen as impossible to do both of these without a [race](https://lwn.net/Articles/773459/). The race however can be avoided by forking a process to reserve the child pid (eg as its pgid), *as long as that process outlives the parent*. Sending `SIGKILL` instead of `SIGCHLD` is a simple way to maintain that invariant. Thus `SIGKILL` helps achieve overall correctness in the face of random process failure.